Find $\int_{|z|=5} \frac{\sin z}{z^2-4} \hspace{0.2cm} dz$ using Residue Theorem
Find $\int_{|z|=5} \frac{\sin z}{z^2-4} \hspace{0.2cm} dz$ using Residue Theorem
We know that $\sin z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. But how can we manipulate $\frac{1}{z^2-4} = \frac{1}{(z-2)(z+2)}$ so that we can see the $a_{-1}$ term in all of it? This is more of a question regarding manipulation of power (Laurent) series as oppposed to a question about residues

Take a series centred at $z = \pm 2$ instead of $z = 0$ since your residues are at $z = \pm 2$, not $z = 0$.

@Abezhiko I thought about doing the same thing but then it would easily boil down into a Cauchy's Integral formula since you would have a sum of two $k_i \int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ for $f(z)=1$ and $k_i$ is constant

We have the identity:
$$4\int_{|z|=5} \frac{\sin z}{z^2-4} \hspace{0.2cm} = \int_{|z|=5}\frac{\sin z}{z-2}+\int_{|z|=5}\frac{\sin z}{z+2} dz $$
Since $\sin(z)$ is an entire function, $\frac{\sin(z)}{z-2}$ has residue $\sin(2)$ at $z=2$. Similarly  $\frac{\sin(z)}{z+2}$ has residue $\sin(-2)$ at $z=-2$. Applying the residue theorem gives you the answer.
P/s: It can be seen immediately that $\int_{|z|=5}\frac{\sin z}{z-2} = 2\pi i\sin(2)$ using Cauchy integral formula.

I will give you two appraoches.
We have two poles, one at z = 2 one at z = -2
$\int_\gamma \frac {f(z)}{z-a} dz = 2\pi i f(a)$  if $a$ is in the contour and $f(a)$ is defined.
If we rewrite $\frac {\sin z}{(z+2)(z-2)}$ as  $\frac {\frac {\sin z}{(z+2)}}{(z-2)}$ we can evaluate it at $z=2$ as above.
Then we evaluate $\frac {\frac {\sin z}{(z-2)}}{(z+2)}$ at $z=-2$
Or we can use partial fractions.
$\frac {\sin z}{z^2-4} = \frac {\frac 14\sin z}{z-2} - \frac {\frac 14\sin z}{z+2}$
And evaluate those residuals.
